# what is location of image?

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api

Where to store image?
I want to post an image to wall of facebook using graph api.I came to know that ,facebook is not allowing localhost image.Image should be on the live server.I don't have that much space on the server.Then what is option?How can I post an image to facebook page or wall?

Comment: The question is not very clear

Answer (score 0):

You can store Image in database by using data type "image “or by converting in “binary”.

Thanks

Comment: i not getting your question clearly.. please can you post more about it